# Google Charts - Area Charts with Curved (Smooth) Lines

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to create an area chart in Google Charts but I want the lines to be curved instead of sharp. The option curveType: function seems to work only in line charts. Anyone cracked this earlier?

Comment: provide a code example

Comment: See in JSFiddle: Uncommenting the curveType in options would result in the graph not rendering. It works fine for line charts. Want to know if an option to smooth the lines is present in Area Charts [link]https://jsfiddle.net/aravindfantain/eehtmkzb/1/

Comment: the chart doesn't render because it should be `curveType: 'function'` -- but this option, or any similar option, isn't available on an area chart

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat. The quotes around the function was an oversight, wanted to see if the smoothing option is available in Area Chart similar to Line Chart. Bummer it isn't there, the curved area charts look much slicker!

Comment: Hi, 
Is anyone knows about the same? I am facing the same problem and looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reference to using intervals may be talking about something like the following.  I'm giving JSON versions of options and data here.  The important bits are the options "curveType" and "intervals" (which will set the color of the area under the curve and specify that the interval should be an area), and the two additional columns in the data which define the bottom and top of the interval.  Set the bottom of the interval equal to the value at the bottom of the graph (0 in my case), and the top of the interval equal to the data point.

```
 "options" :   {
      "vAxis" : { "title" : "No. of Results", "titleTextStyle" : { "italic" : false} },
      "series": [{"color" : "#9a5324"}],
      "curveType" : "function",
      "intervals" : { "style" : "area", "color" : "#D49464" },
      "legend" : { "position" : "none" },
      "height" : 320,
      "width" : 355
   }

"data" : [
   [ "Month", "NumResults", { "role" : "annotation" }, { "id" : "iBottom", "type" : "number", "role" : "interval" }, { "id" : "iTop", "type" : "number", "role": "interval" } ],
   [ "Sep-2013",1000, "1000",0,1000 ],
   [ "Oct-2013",1550, "1550",0,1550 ],
   [ "Nov-2013",900,"900", 0,900 ],
   [ "Dec-2013",400,"400",0,400 ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an [issue from 2015](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2110) on the subject. The first comment states:

> Until then, if you want to work at it, it turns out that you could make a
>   smoothed AreaChart using the 'interval' role, combining multiple intervals
>   with styles of area and line. You'll have to add an extra series just so
>   the intervals can be associated with the right domain values. See the
>   details about intervals at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals#area-intervals